# Binomial approximation with additional term

Tags: binomial-coefficients, approximation

From Stirling's approximation we know that
$$\binom{2n}{n}\sim \frac{2^{2n}}{\sqrt{\pi n}}.$$

Is it true that for some constant $c$ and for $n$ large enough,
$$\binom{2n}{n+10}\geq c\cdot\frac{2^{2n}}{\sqrt{\pi n}}?$$

Comment: A more accurate approximation is $$ \binom{2n}{n}\sim \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi\left(n+\tfrac{1}{4}\right)}}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $n>10$,

$$\frac{\binom{2n}{n+10}}{\binom{2n}{n}} = \frac{n!^2}{(n+10)!(n-10)!} $$
and the limit of the RHS as $n\to +\infty$ is just $1$. It follows that for any $c\in(0,1)$ the inequality
$$ \binom{2n}{n+10}\geq c\cdot\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}} $$
holds for any $n$ large enough.